# Help me understand the application on Bayes' Theorem in this case

Tags: optimization, bayes-theorem, dynamic-programming

I am studying a paper (https://www.jstor.org/stable/1804124) which discusses a two period revenue optimization problem as follows

We are trying the sell a single unit of product over two periods, i.e. if the product does not sell in the first period then it can be sold in the second period for another prize , the problem is to find the optimal pricing policy

Data:

- R1 and R2 (Decision Variables) are the prices that you set in period 1 and 2 respectively
- N : Number of customers that a arrive in each period
- f(V)/F(V) : pdf and cdf of the customer's offer prize i.e. customer will buy the product if (V < Ri) (Assumed to be uniform in this case)
- P : probability that the customer is a "window shopper" , this kind of customers do not buy the in any case

So the the problem can be formulated as

$$
Max_{R1 ,R2}  R1*(Prob. sale in  1)+ R2*(Posterior prob. sale in 2)
* (Prob. no sale in 1).
$$

Please help me understand the authors explanation and implementation of bayes rule from here on:

> Now, the probability of a sale in period 1 is
> (1 - F(R1))(1 - P^N), because the probability
> that every customer is a shopper is P N so
> that 1 - P^N is the probability of encounter-
> ing at least one buyer. It only requires one
> buyer to make the sale as long as R1 < V.
> Similarly, the posterior probability of a sale
> in period 2 is (1- F2(R2))(1 -P^N) and the
> probability of no sale in period 1 is 1 - [(1 -
> F(R ))( 1- P^N)].
>
> It is now necessary to derive F2(V). Bayes'
> Theorem states that the posterior probability
> is proportional to the probability of the sam-
> ple, given the parameter, times the prior
> probability of the parameter. The sample in
> this case is the observation that no one
> bought during period 1. For V < R1, the
> probability of no purchase is 1. For V> R1,
> there is only one reason why the good did
> not sell during period 1 and that is that all
> customers were shoppers. This happens with
> probability p^N.
> It is easy to show that the normalization
> required to make the integral of the density
> function equal to 1 is 1/[R1(- P^N)+ P^N]
> so that the density is given by

$$
f_2(V) = \frac{1}{R_1(1-P^N) + P^N}  for V < R1
$$
$$
f_2(V) = \frac{P^N}{R_1(1-P^N) + P^N}  for V > R1
$$

please help me understand the formulation, like where did the the prior probability was function go?